# How does providing updates to an app work in WP7?

Tags: versioning, windows-phone-7

If I build an app for Windows Phone 7 and release V1 they purchase it and download it from the app store. Now let's say there's a bug or I release a new version. How do I publish a new version of the app without them having to pay for downloading a new version of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You publish the update via the marketplace in the same way that you releassed the original version. (Except you say that it's an update.)

Anyone with the app installed will be told that there is an update available and given the option to install it. You can't force the update.

You can't force the upgrade on users.

All updates are free.

If you wanted a paid upgrade/update this would need to be a new app in the Marketplace. You could also remove the old version if/as necessary.

More information at http://developer.windowsphone.com/Marketplace.aspx